# Mocha loop at the middle of describe function

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, foreach, mocha.js

Can we run a dynamical loop test in mocha when we obtain the dynamic array from one of the test cases something like below?

```
describe('test', () {
  var array = []; 
  it('test 1', function(done) {
    // get the array
    // assume JSON = [ {number : 1, value : 1}, {number : 2, value : 2}]
  }
  // run loop test base on the array from test 1
  array.forEach() {
    it(`test {array.number}`, function(done) {
      // sample
      expect(array.number).to.be.equal(array.value)
    }
  }

  it('test 3', function(done) {
    // another test 
  }
}
```

So far, it seems to work fine if I ran in a separate js file instead of just one js file by passing the result of the JSON array (callback) to another test js file. What if I want it in one js file?

Reference: https://mochajs.org/#dynamically-generating-tests

Comment: In the way shown here, most likely not. There seems to be some asynchronous operations going on which probably mess up your sequence of execution. In general however, it is possible to generate test cases dynamically.

Comment: Could you describe a little bit more specifically what you'd like to do with the array or what your current working state is and what you'd ideally like it to be? It seems a little ambiguous from the questions.

Comment: @Azarro the JSON objects contain a list of test cases from a server(tool) that I need to run with Mocha. For example, I send a request to the server (tool) that I'm going to run profile B (a profile contains 7 test cases). Then, I obtain the test cases from profile B and run them with a specific sequence of flow. I also could obtain test cases from profile A and run them with another sequence of flow. Basically, each profile contains a different type of test case. My objective is to use the test cases from the server (tool) and run/test the requirement of the profile.

Comment: @Sirko could you please explain more on "generate test cases dynamically"? Do you have any resources that I can read? The reason I try to fit them into one JS file is that it is under the same test suites. Basically, I have different test suites (profile). If I have 4 profiles (let's assume each profile contains 10 test cases). Then I have to run 4 different types of sequence/expected behavior. In this case, it would become a 1 + 4 js file (or could be 4 + 4 since I not sure which array should I pass to which js file).

Comment: I dont have specific resources at hand right now. for Repetitive tests, I used JSON files for inputs and outputs in the past. I imported them by the default means of node.js and then had a loop creating the actual tests. Overall, this is pretty straight forward. The only hickups may come from asynchronous code not being executed  in the order you might expect.